# How to check if a string is in a list, using a function on each item (python3)

Tags: python, string

I am making a program that is like AI that responds back. I started coding this project but hit a roadblock. I wanted to take a list of words, then check if a given string is inside a list while returning a bool. My code looks something like this...

```
listofhellos = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey!!!']
if listofhellos.lower() == 'hello': 
# This checks if string 'hello' is in listofhellos
    print('Hey, how are you?')
    # if it is in the list then print out a response
```

Thank You!

Comment: `if 'hello' in listofhellos`

Comment: Hi! Though the linked question is related, your request is about checking each item in sequence (using `.lower()`, but maybe any other function), so it's a subtly different request. I edited your title to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Solution:

```
listofhellos = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey!!!']
check = "Hello"
if check.lower() in listofhellos:
    print('Exists')
else:
    print("Not exists")
```

Comment: Seems ok, but what if `listofhellos` comes from a user, that puts uppercase character at beginning of each word?

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
if 'hello' in map(str.lower, ['hello', 'hi', 'Hey!!!']):
```

or

````
return 'hello' in map(str.lower, ['hello', 'hi', 'Hey!!!']):```
````

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) built-in function in conjonction with [the Python 'list comprehension'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (well,in fact a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)):

```py
if any(item.lower() == 'hello' for item in listofhellos):
    print('hey, how are you?')
```

This will go over each items of your list in order, test it, and return `True` at the first item that verifies your test.